# Memory leak using TensorFlow for Java

Tags: java, memory-leaks, tensorflow

The following test code leaks memory:

```
private static final float[] X = new float[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};

public void testTensorFlowMemory() {
    // create a graph and session
    try (Graph g = new Graph(); Session s = new Session(g)) {
        // create a placeholder x and a const for the dimension to do a cumulative sum along
        Output x = g.opBuilder("Placeholder", "x").setAttr("dtype", DataType.FLOAT).build().output(0);
        Output dims = g.opBuilder("Const", "dims").setAttr("dtype", DataType.INT32).setAttr("value", Tensor.create(0)).build().output(0);
        Output y = g.opBuilder("Cumsum", "y").addInput(x).addInput(dims).build().output(0);
        // loop a bunch to test memory usage
        for (int i=0; i<10000000; i++){
            // create a tensor from X
            Tensor tx = Tensor.create(X);
            // run the graph and fetch the resulting y tensor
            Tensor ty = s.runner().feed("x", tx).fetch("y").run().get(0);
            // close the tensors to release their resources
            tx.close();
            ty.close();
        }

        System.out.println("non-threaded test finished");
    }
}
```

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?  The basic flow is to create a graph and a session on that graph, create a placeholder and a constant in order to do a cumulative sum on a tensor fed in as x.  After running the resulting y operation, I close both the x and y tensors to free their memory resources.

Things I believe so far to help:

- This is not a Java objects memory problem.  The heap does not grow, other memory in the JVM is not growing- according to jvisualvm.  Doesn't appear to be a JVM memory leak according to Java's Native Memory Tracking.
- The close operations are helping, if they're not there the memory grows by leaps and bounds.  With them in place it still grows pretty fast, but nearly as much as without them.
- The cumsum operator is not important, it happens with sum and other operators as well
- It happens on Mac OS with TF 1.1, and CentOS 7 with TF 1.1 and 1.2_rc0
- Commenting out the `Tensor ty` lines removes the leak, so it appears to be in there.

Any ideas?  Thanks!  Also, [here's a Github project that demonstrates this issue](https://github.com/jpangburn/tensorflowmemorytest) with both a threaded test (to grow the memory faster) and an unthreaded test (to show it's not due to threading).  It uses maven and can be run with simple:

```
mvn test
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with TenserFlow but it seems that you're not closing any of the `Session` object that you create (`Session s = new Session(g)`) and only the first `Tensor` object in the list returned by `Session.Runner.run()` (`s.runner().feed("x", tx).fetch("y").run().get(0)` only first `get(0)`).

Comment: Do we know exactly what type of objects are the roots for these leaks?  This can really help us to determine where the problem is.  (If you're not sure how, tools like VisualVM can help you find out.)

Comment: @Titus Great suggestions Titus!  For the Session, this is the relatively new [Java try-with-resources syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) so the Session and Graph objects get closed automatically, but they're outside the loop that's causing it to grow.  The `get(0)` I think is OK because there's only one fetch so only one result (I verified with debugger).  Lastly, the JVM memory isn't growing (heap, etc.), I checked with jvisualvm.

Comment: @JoeC I should have been more clear, it's not Java objects causing the leak.  The heap doesn't grow, verified with jvisualvm.  Also, there's not a JVM native memory leak, I checked with jcmd using the summary memory check.  As far as I can tell, the C code that TensorFlow uses is allocating memory and not releasing it.  Closing the tx and ty objects releases C resources, not just Java.  So figure I'm missing something else!

Comment: In the `Tensor ty` line, several method calls are chained - any chance that one of the intermediary objects needs explicit closing too?

Comment: @ErichKitzmueller great question, thanks!  I was wondering exactly this since that line seems guilty but the samples they give do it the same way.  Seems ash has confirmed there's a bug in the library though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe there is indeed a leak (in particular a missing `TF_DeleteStatus` corresponding to the [allocation in JNI code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/java/src/main/native/session_jni.cc#L191)) (Thanks for the detailed instructions to reproduce)

I'd encourage you to file an issue at http://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues
and hopefully it should be fixed before the final 1.2 release.

(Relatedly, you also have a leak outside the loop since the `Tensor` object created by `Tensor.create(0)` is not being closed)

**UPDATE**: This was fixed and 1.2.0-rc1 should no longer have this problem.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that!  I'll file the issue with a link here and to my github example.  Good spot on the setup code too.  Fortunately my real problem is a graph built in Python that was leaking when I ran something similar to this in Java.  This test harness was just to expose the leak in simplest possible setup :-)  I'll fix it before posting the issue for clarity.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10119) is the corresponding github issue