# When can Tensor.close() be called when using the Java Tensorflow API

Tags: java, tensorflow

I understand that Tensors as exposed by the Java API implement AutoCloseable which allows for convenient resource management via a try-with-resources block.

```
try(Tensor<Float> t = Tensors.create(1.0f)){
    doSomethingWithATensor(t);
}
```

The programer should ensure that 'close()' is called on all tensors so no resources are leaked.

There are times when "doSomethingWithATensor" adds an operation to the tensorflow graph. For example when creating a constant.

```
try(Graph g = new Graph()){
    try(Tensor<Float> t = Tensors.create(1.0f)){
        Output<Float> constant = g.opBuilder("Const", "c")
            .setAttr("dtype", DataType.FLOAT)
            .setAttr("value", t)
            .build().output(0);
    }
    try(Session s = new Session(g)){
        Tensor<Float> u = s.runner().fetch(constant).run().get(0).expect(Float.class);
        u.close();
    }
}
```

My question is why is it OK for "t" to be deallocated before the session has done whatever it is going to do with it? The 'close()' method on Tensor calls TF_DeleteTensor in the C API, which states that the tensor is destroyed. This usage model is present in an official [tensorflow example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/examples/LabelImage.java) the relevant code for which is given below:

```
<T> Output<T> constant(String name, Object value, Class<T> type) {
  try (Tensor<T> t = Tensor.<T>create(value, type)) {
    return g.opBuilder("Const", name)
        .setAttr("dtype", DataType.fromClass(type))
        .setAttr("value", t)
        .build()
        .<T>output(0);
  }
}
```

Is the ".setAttr" method creating a copy of t?

The only other stackoverflow question I could find related to this [discusses a memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44082297/memory-leak-using-tensorflow-for-java)